# EC2 connect RDS using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

i know this has been asked but none of the threads had a solution that worked for me
I am connecting to RDS from XAMPP (local) with success
Also i am connecting fine with mySql workbench
Having problems connecting from EC2
getting error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`
this is what my PHP looks like:

```
define("HOST", "mydatabase-starter.Pzw9yv81CmMJ.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306");
define("DBUSER", "mydatabaseUser");
define("PASS", "**********");
define("DB", "mydatabase");

die("Going to connect now, wish me luck!");
$conn = mysql_connect(HOST, DBUSER, PASS) or die();
$db = mysql_select_db(DB) or die();
```

also, the security from RDS looks like this![image]

EC2 is a lamp stack, fresh install of apache and php, without mysql.
what am i doing wrong?  are there any other services i am missing?

UPDATE: from SSH, i can connect to RDS by:
`sudo mysql -h mydatabase-starter.Pzw9yv81CmMJ.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mydatabaseUser -p`
* this will output "Going to connect now, wish me luck!" from the PHP file
but looks like the connection doesnt  happen when it is on EC2

Comment: Are you getting anything useful from `mysql_error()` after the connect fails?

Comment: i dont get an output,  its like the connection doesnt even happen when its on AWS

Comment: Hmm. Is port 3306 on your EC2 instance allowing outbound traffic?

Comment: 3306 > out? where can i check this?

Comment: Quickest way is probably the [Amazon EC2 online management panel](http://aws.amazon.com/). Log in at the top right of the page, click through to EC2, and look at the security settings for your instance.

Comment: Is the code that's making the connection even being called? What happens if you put `die("Going to connect now, wish me luck!");` on the line before the `mysql_connect` call?

Comment: regarding security of 3306 OUT,  i only see Inbound

Comment: One reason you're not seeing output - write `...or die (mysql_error())`

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @Stu yes, it is all documented here.  are you still having issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the php-mysql. I guess you are using Amazon Linux AMI so try

```
sudo yum install php-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

It means MySQL extension is not loaded on your EC2 Instance. Depending on your distro, you must install it.

On Debian / Ubuntu, you should run command like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: but my EC2 instance is connecting to RDS which is the database instance. would i still need to install mysql on EC2?

Comment: No, you don't need to install MySQL and php5-mysql is not Server, but MySQL module for php5 and you need it to interact with RDS.

Comment: tried 'sudo yum install php5-mysql' but got this No package php5-mysql available.

Comment: take out the 5, `sudo yum install php-mysql`

Comment: Searching for Packages with yum: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-searching-packages.html